# Blackberry http connection using WiFi when not entering event dispatcher

Tags: exception, networking, blackberry, wifi

My application can run in 2 modes first one instantiates itself after going into main() enters event dispatcher then works as normal.

MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
theApp.enterEventDispatcher();

In another (used to update some background stuff) it does not enter into event dispatcher just runs an http request and does some extra stuff.

Everything works fine(network connections etc) except when I try to use ;interface=wifi as a part of my URL without entering dispatcher (works fine if I do). I get this exception **Uncaught exception: no Application instance** when I try to establish a connection:

temp = Connector.open( url, mode, timeouts );

One other difference is that when I am doing a request not entering into even dispatcher I do not spawn a separate thread (works perfectly when using any other connection but WiFi)

I detect wifi using WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED, jde version 4.3

Any ideas?